# function __construct in BaseController

Tags: laravel

I want to declare a global variable. Here are my actions

BaseController

```
protected $header_data;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->header_data = HeaderData::all();
        View::share('data', $this->header_data);
    }
```

Next, in the Blog page controller, let's say I write this

```
$this->header_data;
```

And on the page itself in php.blade

```
<h1>{{ $data }}</h1>
```

But I get completely all the data from the model, and I only need a field `data`

`[{"id":3,"url":"\/blog","data":"<title>Blog<\/title>\n<meta name=\"description\" content=\"Blog\" \/>","created_at":"2021-10-19T11:24:41.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-10-19T11:24:41.000000Z"}]`

Comment: ***...to update the data...*** what data?

Comment: @kiner_shah added to post

Comment: I recommend, sending a response for POST request containing the number of likes/dislikes. And on success, you update the `div` contents from jQuery.

Comment: @chu take a look at this tutorial: https://makitweb.com/like-unlike-using-ajax-jquery-php/

Answer (score 2):

> when I click on the like to update the data, I reload the page using
> `window.location.reload();`
>
> Can this somehow be done without reloading the page?

Yes, by not using `window.location.reload();`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: href,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  },
  error: function (jqXhr, status, error) {
    alert(error);
  },
});
```

Change your PHP so it doesn't return the complete page for POST requests to the `/article/...?type=heart` route.

In case of a "like" functionality, you practically only need feedback whether it has worked (the like was registered), or not (in which case you might want to display an error).

Your server could simply respond with [status code 204 (No Content)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) in the success case.